# passive java transformation for passthrough

Tags: java, informatica-powercenter

I am new to informatica and using passive java transformation to implement a small logic, and I am using passthru fields in java transformation to maintain the order of the fields in the file. I wanted to ask if a passive java transformation can be used to pass through the fields?
Do I need to set input ports equal to output ports for all the fields that are passing through even if they are not being used in java code (the file has around 150 fields). I am using passive transformation bc I want to process 1 output row for every input row. I searched online but I am not very clear on this question. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your java transformation is passive, you do not need to pass all the fields through java transformation. Just connect the ports from previous transformation to next transformation skipping the Java transformation.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, an active transformation is where the number of records and order of records coming into the transformation is not the same as that going out of the transformation... the reason this is important is because it represents boundaries or milestones within the mapping that all records have to reach that point before they can be further processed.

This is opposed to the one in one out processing that occurs for passive transformations like an expression transformation

If you processed 4 active transformations in succession then the time taken to complete the process would be the sum of the completion time of each as each transformation would have to complete processing all records before the next one started (serialization)

If you processed 4 passive transformations in succession then the time taken to complete the process would be the time for the slowest transformation to complete processing all the records which could be comparitively a 4th of the time.

Also active transformations need more thinking to ensure no ports bypass them but its not like you're gonna abandon sorting and filtering anytime soon so dont avoid them  just learn how they work

Comment: It may not be true, I'm afraid. Or - at least - not precise. Active transformations processing does not need to be serialized. Consider few filters, one after another. Second one will not wait untill first one processes all rows. It would need to cache the data, while filters do not create cache at all. They will be processed simultaneously. Actually, after the mapping is compiled, it may be even reduced. Even other active transformations like joiner or aggregator will often send rows for further processing before they process the whole set.

Comment: Fair play, perhaps not completely true but a helpful way for someone new to the tool to visualise why powercenter enforces measures to ensure you don't bypass an active transformation. In the case of filters and aggregators the ports which bypass these transformations will no longer have a matching record to be associated with and thus join rules will have to be explicitly specified through a joiner transformation